# Error 1 Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'double'

Tags: c#, .net

I believe what i am trying to do is very simple but I get the error. 
Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'double'

I want to multiply the number of days that have been stored in dayrental by the amount 19.95 if that checkbox is checked. I get the error that says I cant because dayrental is a method. 
How can I get the value from dayrental so that I can multiple by 19.95?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double rental;
        dayrental();
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            rental = dayrental * 19.95;
        label4.Text = Convert.ToString(rental);




    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void dayrental()
    {
        var timeSpan = dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value;
        var rentalDays = timeSpan.Days;                      
        //label4.Text = Convert.ToString(rentalDays);   
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your syntax is just a little off (missing parentheses after function call and no return type specified for your function).

```
if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    rental = dayrental() * 19.95;

public double dayrental()
{
    var timeSpan = dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value;
    return (double) timeSpan.Days;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`dayrental` is a function that return void.

it has no value and you cannot multiply it by 19

Answer (score 0):

In c# a methodcall is always denoted by a pair of braces, while the method itself is addressed by it's name. So `dayrental()` is the returnvalue of dayrental, while `dayrental` is the method dayrental. Therefore you are multiplying the method dayrental with the with 19.95 which obviously fails.
What you are trying to do is:

```
rental = dayrental() * 19.95;
```

Also dayrental returns void so youm ight want to change it to

```
 public double dayrental()
```

and return some value.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the paranthesis from your function call to dayrental, which is causing the compiler to think you are refering to the method itself rather than the result of a call to that method.

```
rental = dayrental * 19.95;
```

should be

```
rental = dayrental() * 19.95;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double rental;

    var dayRental = dayrental();

    if(checkBox1.Checked == true)
       rental = dayrental * 19.95;

    label4.Text = Convert.ToString(rental);  
}

private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public int dayrental()
{
     var timeSpan = dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value;

     var rentalDays = timeSpan.Days;                      

     return rentalDays;
}
```